# $x=Px+Qx$ unique decomposition in Hilbert space

Tags: proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

**Problem:**

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of Hilbert space $H$. Then
every $x \in H$ has unique decomposition
$x = Px + Qx$ where $Px \in M$, $Qx \in M^{\perp}$ .

**I don't understand:** When proving that our constructed $Qx$ is in $M^{\perp}$, we want to show that  $(Qx,y)=0$  $\forall y\in M$. Then in every single proof I have seen, we assume WLOG $||y||=1.$ Why is this possible? How do we generalize?

**Sample proof from Piotr Hajlasz:**
The set
$x + M = \{x + y : y \in M\}$
is convex and closed. Let $Qx$ be the element of the smallest norm in $x + M$
and let $Px = x − Qx$. Clearly $x = Px + Qx$. Since $Qx \in x + M$, it follows
that $Px \in M$. We still need to prove that $Qx \in M^{\perp}$. To this end we have to
prove that $(Qx, y) = 0$ for all $y \in M$. We can assume that $||y|| = 1$. Denote
$z = Qx$. The minimizing property of $Qx$ shows that
$$(z, z) = ||z||^2 \leq ||z − αy||^2 = (z − αy, z − αy)$$
for all $α \in K$. Hence
$$(z, z) ≤ (z, z) + |α|^2(y, y) - α(y,z) - \overline{α}(z,y),$$
$$0 \leq |α|^2 − α(y, z) − \overline{α}(z, y).$$
Taking $α = (z, y)$ we have
$$0 \leq −|(z, y)|^2$$
,
i.e. $(z, y) = 0$. This proves that $z = Qx \in M^{\perp}$.

Comment: For general $y$, consider $(Qx,y)=\|y\|(Qx,\frac{y}{\|y\|})$, which is zero if you have already proved the orthogonality for unitary vectors

Comment: Thank you both Lorenzo Pompili and SolubleFish for the quick answer (I can't even accept an answer for the question yet), I understand now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof in OP shows that $(z,y) = 0$ for every $y \in M$ such that $\|y\| =1$. Let us prove that the result holds for any $y\in M$.

Let $y\in M$. If $y= 0$, then $(z,y) = 0$. If $y\neq 0$, then $\|y\| \neq 0$ and $\| y/\|y\|\| = 1$. Therefore, by OP's proof, we have :
$$(z,y) = \|y\| \left(z,\frac{y}{\|y\|} \right)  = \|y\|\cdot 0 =0$$

Therefore $(z,y) = 0$ for any $y\in M$